# Creating "constructor function": __new__ with the __init__'s signature

Tags: python

The problem is simple: I want to create a callable reference to the "constructor" of some class. And I want that constructor function to have correct signature.

The answer is not just `func = MyClass` since it lacks the signature (and is not quite a function).

```
>>> inspect.signature(MyClass.__call__)
<Signature (*args, **kwargs)>
```

The answer is not just `func = MyClass.__new__` since it lacks the signature.

```
>>> inspect.signature(MyClass.__new__)
<Signature (*args, **kwargs)>
```

The answer is not just `func = MyClass.__init__` since it returns None and needs a `self`.

```
>>> inspect.signature(MyClass.__init__)
<Signature (self, a, b)>
```

So, I need `__new__` with the `__init__`'s signature (but without self).

```
func = MyClass.???
inspect.signature(func)
<Signature (a, b)>
```

What's the easiest way to make it?

Comment: "The answer is not just func = MyClass". Err, that is the answer. Classes are callable and it doesn't lack the signature like you stated. `inspect.signature(MyClass)` → `<Signature (a, b)>`

Comment: `__new__` and `__init__` are completely different things. Their signatures have nothing to do with each other. `__new__` creates the object (`self`) that is then passed to `__init__`. What you want sounds like a combination of `__new__` + `__init__` - which is the `type(MyClass).__call__` method. Now obviously if you have a wrapper of two functions - the more generic of the two will be exposed. Hence the `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: @rdas I think that I know pretty well what __new__ and __init__ are and their differences. Speaking about obviousness, both __init__ and __new__ accept arguments and I see not much reason why __new__ could not have had a proper signature like __init__.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Wow. You're right >_< I did not realize that signatures of `MyClass` and `MyClass.__call__` might be different. But but but signature must belong to some function. What function does `inspect.signature(MyClass)` belong to if not `MyClass.__call__`?

Comment: `inspect.signature` has special treatment for classes. If your class has a metaclass that implements `__call__`, it returns that signature. If your class implements `__new__`, it returns that. And finally, if it implements `__init__`, it returns that.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        print(a)

Test("hello","world")
func = Test.__call__
func("foo","bar")
```

(*args, **kwargs) is very similar to (a, b) with *args being the array of required arguments and **kwargs being the dictionary of optional arguments. So you can call it normally and the syntactic sugar will change the array into arguments.

Comment: `list`, not array.

Comment: This only works because `Test` doesn't define a `__call__` method. The correct way to do it would be to set `func = Test` - or. if you insist on using `__call__`, it would be `func = type(Test).__call__.__get__(Test)`.

Comment: I think I have specifically mentioned this variant and wrote why this does not work for me. Namely: "(*args, **kwargs) is very similar to (a, b)" [citation needed]